# Git not seen from shell although the plugins are installed

Tags: git, jenkins

In my Jenkins installation I have the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and the [Git Client Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin) . Also, in *Global Tool Configuration -> Git installations -> Git* I selected `Install Automatically`.

I thought that because of this, Git should be visible whenever I reference it from a Jenkins build.

However, in a job that has a script with this line:

```
sh("git push origin --tags")
```

I get `git: command not found`.

Any idea why git is not visible although it should be installed by Jenkins?

Comment: I guess the path to the git commend is not exported. Try to use the git with the path to the executable git command

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: Git is installed in a path. It must be exported to use it from the Shell or you have to add this path in front of the git command like `/<path_to_git_client_installation>/git`

Answer (score 1):

The **automated installation only applies to other plugins** that require a tool. E.g., the `git` tool installer will be used if you do SCM checkouts via the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)

**Automated installation will *not* add the `git` command to your default (shell) path**.

Instead, **you can use the [Tool Environment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tool+Environment+Plugin) to access tools that were deployed via automated installation**. That will

- trigger automated installation on slave side
- provide the tool path as environment variable

That variable you can then use to run the tool from groovy/shell/... build steps.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even install this. (I'm getting a 407)

Comment: That's a different issue. But in any case, it should be clear now why the `git` command cannot be found in your script's path.